# Can't open mime-attachment.ics attachment in calendar on iPhone

Tags: ios, calendar

Since I installed iOS 7 on my iPhone I can not open mime-attachment.ics (invitation sent from an Outlook email) files in my calendar. Does anyone know what i can do to open these files in my calendar?

<sup>iPhone 5, iOS 7.0.4</sup>

Comment: Are the invitations showing in the Calendar app? Check the "Inbox" link in the bottom right of the yearly/monthly/weekly+daily views to see.

Comment: no they are not showing up in the inbox.